# Phil Sturgeon's Cache Library

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

Ok here is the link to the cache library he wrote: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-cache

Anyway, his documentation is absolutely.. vague and not helpful at all. I know it's self explanatory.. to a point.

```
$this->cache->model('blog_m', 'getPosts', array($category_id, 'live'), 120); // keep for 2 minutes
```

What is the 3rd parameter?
And is that what creates the cache or this what creates a cache file:

```
$this->cache->write($data, 'cached-name');
```

And if that is, what exactly is $data suppose to be holding a value of? The overall query orrr...??
If anyone could give explanation on this on how you create a cache file.. Basically I want to cache the query that selects a bunch of news postings.. and everytime a new new post is created, to delete that cache and recache it so it shows the new news posting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation seems to be fairly clear. Anyways, I'll try to explain it in better terms:

```
// cached model call
$this->cache->model('blog_m', 'getPosts', array($category_id, 'live'), 120); // keep for 2 minutes
```

This calls the method `getPosts` on the model `blog_m` and caches the result for 120 seconds. If you make the same call again within the next 2min, it will return the cached results, otherwise it will fetch the data from the database and update the cache. It's good for methods on models that you will be calling very frequently.

If you want to manually add and get data from a cache, then you use:

```
// cached array or object
$this->cache->write($data, 'cached-name');
$data = $this->cache->get('cached-name');
```

`$data` will hold whatever you want to cache. If you want to cache the user's email, for example, here's how you would cache and fetch it

```
$email = 'foobar@example.com';
$this->cache->write($email, 'user-email');
// to fetch
$user_email = $this->cache->get('user-email');
```

Comment: Ok the thing is.. I asked what the third parameter is. I know what caching does and what it involves. The ARRAY is what I dont get.. the third parameter in the model() function.. What array do I put into the parameter??

Comment: That array is the arguments you want to pass to the method being called on the model.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh WOW So instead of calling the model, like $this->news->get_news($id), you would do $this->cache->model('news_model', 'get_news', array($id), 120); or whatever seconds you want to cache it for??

Comment: And what if it called another method, would it cache the queries in that sub-method as well? Or no? Because there is a query I want to not cache in the sub method.

Comment: I haven't looked through the source code, but my guess is it only caches the return value of the function you call. If it has the reutrn value cached, it will just return you that value witout calling the function or any other functions that function might call